# Pre-authentication failed: Password read interrupted while getting initial credentials

Tags: linux, hadoop, kerberos, keytab

This is something I have faced and I found the solution. since there
wasn't any question about it, I will post it as a question and I will
write my solution as the answer.

**Environment**:

- OS: Centos Linux, MacOS (Big Sur)
- Cluster: Cloudera Hadoop Distribution,
- Tool: Kerberos

**Problem**:

I created "user.keytab" file by "ktutil" to renew the krb ticket without password as it was recommended in here https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh

```
ktutil:  addent -password -p user@DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
Password for user@DOMAIN.LOCAL: [enter your password]
ktutil:  addent -password -p user@DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e aes256-cts
Password for user@DOMAIN.LOCAL: [enter your password]
ktutil:  wkt user.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

then testing end up with exception

```
(user@server [~])$ kinit user@DOMAIN.LOCAL -k -t user.keytab
kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials
```

Comment: @jww what's the point of a Kerberos tag if not for questions like this? I'd argue it absolutely is relevant. Look at some of the "related" questions - many are highly upvoted and often fairly theoretical.

Comment: This kind of question is really a gray area, it falls in between the lines of development and system administration in my view.  Question could fall into either category.   Anyway, looking forward to the answer.

Comment: @Ben - In theory, the Kerberos tag is for programming and development question related to Kerberos, like configuring, make'ing, fixing bugs, implementing a new signature algorithm, etc. But it would not be the first time a tag became a dumping ground on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15):

### Cause:

key encryption type "aes256-cts" might not be configured in your krb setup

### Solution

simply delete keytab file and recreate one without "aes256-cts" encryption by using above steps

```
ktutil:  addent -password -p user@DOMAIN.LOCAL -k 1 -e rc4-hmac
Password for user@DOMAIN.LOCAL: [enter your password]
ktutil:  wkt user.keytab
ktutil:  quit
```

or

delete "aes256-cts" encription from the keytab file by following the steps on the link I added above.

and finally execute:

```
(user@server [~])$ kinit user@DOMAIN.LOCAL -k -t user.keytab
```

you wont see any error this time and your ticket will be created

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: In my case issue has been fixed after using the salt option in ktutil.

Below is the steps which i used to fix the issue.

[user@rhel8server ~]$ ktutil

ktutil:  addent -password -p USER@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE -k 0 -e aes256-cts -s "DOMAIN.EXAMPLEUSER"

Password for USER@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE:
ktutil:  wkt /home/user/kerberos/user.keytab
ktutil:  exit

Comment: Now, rc4-hmac encryption is deprecated, the right solution in this times is the @Namasivayam Chinnapillai one